# Home desktop slows down internet when in sleep mode

Tags: wireless-networking, performance

I have a desktop computer with a LAN connection and a TV with a Roku stick. Whenever my desktop computer goes to sleep, my Internet speed is reduced. If I am using my Roku, the streaming quality gets poor and "boxy" looking. If I use a smartphone and connect to the network using Wi-Fi again, I get a reduced Internet speed. Once I wake the computer from sleep the Internet speed returns to normal.

What do you think it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your PC really sleeping, or could it be doing other tasks, e.g downloading updates, coin-mining (malware) etc.? If the issue does *not* occur when the computer is **completely** shut down, then I'd suspect some background process.

First, do a full shutdown: For Windows, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `shutdown /s /t 0` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should bypass Hybrid shutdown.

If Roku runs at full speed during this shutdown, then:

- Scan for malware, including **browser add-ons, even on Linux distros**. For Windows OS, don't rely only on your existing anti-malware suite, but also do a boot scan from [another antivirus](https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785).
- Check for any ongoing updates, whatever your OS.

BTW, it makes it easier to troubleshoot if you provide specific information, e.g. OS.